# If $G_{ab}$ is cyclic then $G$ is cyclic

Tags: group-theory

In my notes I have the following theorem:

> Let $G$ be a (nilpotent?) group. Suppose that $G_{ab}$ is cyclic. Then $G$ is cyclic.

Actually I don't know if the hypothesis that $G$ is nilpotent is necessary here.  Denote moreover $G_{ab}=G/[G,G]$, $\gamma_2(G)=[G,G]$ and $\gamma_3(G)=[\gamma_2(G),G]$.

Then the proof goes as follows:

it is sufficient to show that $G$ is abelian, hence we would have $G=G_{ab}$ which is cyclic. Suppose by contradiction that $G$ is not abelian, i.e. $\gamma_2(G) \neq 1$. Now, since
$$G/\gamma_3(G) = (\gamma_2(G)/\gamma_3(G))\langle g\gamma_3(G)\rangle = \textbf{Z}(G/\gamma_3(G))\langle g\gamma_3(G)\rangle$$
it follows that $G/\gamma_3(G)$ is abelian.

However, we have that (Why? This is not explained in my notes) $\gamma_3(G)=1$, hence we reach a contradiction.

My question is: why do we have $\gamma_3(G)=1$? Maybe do we need nilpotency of $G$ to get this contradiction?

Comment: You should be able to come up with an example where it fails for a nonnilpotent group. For nilpotent groups it reduces to the case of $p $-groups which is easy.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Your suggestion only works for finite nilpotent groups, and the result is true in general.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ahh, of course. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you definitely need to assume that $G$ is nilpotent. Do you know the result that says if $G/Z(G)$ is cyclic then $G$ is abelian? Apply that to $G/\gamma_3(G)$ to deduce that $\gamma_2(G)=\gamma_3(G)$ and hence (assuming that $G$ is nilpotent) $\gamma_2(G)=1$ so $G$ is abelian.